# How to append static string to a formatted array using PL/pgSQL

Tags: postgresql, indexing, format, plpgsql

I am trying create a geospatial index on a large number of tables using PL/pgSQL. Each index has to be unique so I am trying to append a static string to the end of each table name for the index name. This is the test code I have tried:

```
DO
$do$
DECLARE
    m   text;
    arr text[] := array['E09000001','E09000002'];
BEGIN
   FOREACH m IN ARRAY arr
   LOOP
        EXECUTE format($fmt$
            CREATE INDEX %1$L || '_gist_index'
            ON %1$I
            USING GIST (wkb_geometry);
        $fmt$, m);
   END LOOP;
END
$do$
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR: syntax error at or near "'E09000001'" 
LINE 2: CREATE INDEX 'E09000001' || '_gist_index'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add the postfix in the argument:

```
DO
$do$
DECLARE
    m   text;
    arr text[] := array['E09000001','E09000002'];
BEGIN
   FOREACH m IN ARRAY arr
   LOOP
        EXECUTE format($fmt$
            CREATE INDEX %I
            ON %I
            USING GIST (wkb_geometry);
        $fmt$, m || '_gist_index', m);
   END LOOP;
END
$do$
```